# Apache ErrorDocument line break

Tags: apache-http-server

How to add line break character to the response?

I have this config

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Hello\nWorld"
```

I expected it will return a response with 2 lines

```
Hello
World
```

But it actually output the `\n` literally `Hello\nWorld`